# How to run libreoffice from start menu?

Tags: 10.04, libreoffice, menu

I just installed libreoffice in my Lucid through official PPA at http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/. It won't start from start menu but it works if I run it through terminal with `sudo`. Below the output when I try to run libreoffice from start menu. Thank you.

`ecd: 58: can't cd to ../lib/libreoffice/program`

`exec: 180: /usr/bin/X11/oosplash: not found`

Comment: How did you install libreoffice? With synaptic?

Comment: Yes I was using synaptic. Do you know why it happened?

Comment: No. If you had installed it with a different method, I would have suspected that to be the source of the problem, but I have never seen such a thing. You didn't experiment with programs and permissions, I guess?

Comment: No I didn't. But if the only way is using `sudo`, do you know how to edit `libreoffice --calc %U` command in the main menu so I can execute libreoffice as `sudo`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a good idea. All your documents will belong to root, so then you will need sudo access for moving them around - the problem will grow and grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded Libreoffice's DEBS from their official website, reinstall it, and somehow my problem solved. I still don't know though, why the installation from their official PPA behave that way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was because I had `/usr/bin/X11` before `/usr/bin` in my `PATH`. When I put `/usr/bin` before `/usr/bin/X11`, the problem disappeared.

Comment: I added the ==> lines in the libreoffice script to allow a directory which is a symbolic link itself

        sd_res=$0
        while [ -h "$sd_res" ] ; do
            cd "`dirname "$sd_res"`"
    ==>     # the directory name can also be a symbolic link
    ==>     cd `/bin/pwd`
            sd_basename=`basename "$sd_res"`
            sd_res=`ls -l "$sd_basename" | sed "s/.*$sd_basename -> //g"`
        done
        cd "`dirname "$sd_res"`"

Comment: It's strange that `/usr/bin/X11` being before `/usr/bin` would cause this problem, since on Ubuntu `/usr/bin/X11` is just a symbolic link to `/usr/bin` itself. Was the OS on which you had this problem Ubuntu?